# Vue use the compiler-included build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I'm getting a Vue warn that prevents my page from loading:

ps: I'm NOT using `build` I'm using `yarn serve`

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

(found in <Root>)
```

I know this is because of the default mode of Vue, I tried rewriting webpack but its not working still.

This is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './resources/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './public/javascripts/bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

And my `main.js` config (I believe this is a router issue)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'

// **
// * Components
import Login from './routes/Login';

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'login', component: Login},
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Fixed my warning problem, now I get no error msg and no component is loading

```
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'login',
    data(){
        return {
            name: 'Leo'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The config file you want is `vue.config.js` with the [`runtimeCompiler` option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler) set to `true`

Comment: Ok that did help but it still wont rander my component, updated my question

Comment: Where is your template with `<router-view/>`?

Comment: I strongly suggest you start with a project created using [`vue create`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html), selecting the manual option and checking _"Router"_, etc. That will get you started in the right direction